# How to copy data from docker container to ECS on startup (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have two containers, one is **web-server** based on Node.JS with `assets` directory. Another container is **nginx** which proxify page requests to web-server and getting statics from `assets` directory.

I created AWS cluster, EC2 instance, built and pushed docker images to registry, made tasks to deploy my applications, but I can't share with `assets` directory to **nginx** because directory is not part of this container.

So to solve my problem I figured out to create EFS and attach the volume, add permissions to ec2-user and makes directory available by path `/var/html/assets`.

**Cool and how to copy assets content from my web-server docker container to** `/var/html/assets`**?**

I want to make it public / shared because soon I will make additional servers which should also place assets to this common directory.

The process should be automized and work on each deployment, guys, any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To copy assets content from your web-server docker container to your host machine,
say you want to save your assets content from container to /var/html/assets on host machine, use this command to run your container:

```
docker run --name=nginx -d -v ~/var/html/assets:[Your Container path] -p 5000:80 nginx
```

-v ~/var/html/assets:[Your Container path] Sets up a bindmount volume that links [Your Container path] directory from inside the Nginx container to the ~/var/html/assets directory on the host machine. Docker uses a : to split the host's path from the container path, and the host path always comes first.

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks for answer, I can't influence directly to `docker run` command, unfortunately, because of using AWS ECS.
But I have a AWS Task where I can define the which command to perform.
It's similar to docker compose, but has some differences.

As my assets already pre-built, I think I need to mount a volume and then copy assets by using of instruction in my a "command".

`"command": [
     "/bin/sh",
     "-c",
     "cp -r /web/dist/assets/* /var/www/assets/ && yarn run _production"
 ]`

What do you think about this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by making host directory accessible for writing `chmod 777 /var/html/assets`, then added a volume which is looking to host directory and applied it to `web` and `nginx` containers. When running the `web` container, it invokes `cp` instruction to copy assets to mount directory (host directory). Nginx will see populated directory and can use it.

**Note:** *It's a temporary / workaround solution, giving xrw access to directory is not a good way because of security.*